# How to tell if user has taken photo image Picker

Tags: ios, swift

Basically I want to add a `button` into the `image picker` when the user takes a photo, but before the user presses the `Use Photo` button. As you may know when a user clicks the button to take a photo, the image picker then shows him the taken photo and asks if he wants to retake or use the photo. When that view appears I want to add a button to it so I can perform an action. I only want to add the button when the image is still or taken. I have no idea what function I would use because `didFinishPickingImag`e is after the user clicks use photo. Here is an [image](https://imgur.com/a/o1RRl) of what I am talking about

Comment: You will need to implement your own image picker

Comment: is there a way to at least tell if there was image taken? Like a delegate method?

Comment: Only after the user cancels or selects use photo

Comment: dang, well thats a bummer

Comment: Apple has a AVCam developer sample you can use as a start point

Comment: yea I guess ill just use that. I would think there would be more customization with image pickers

Comment: There are lots of great libraries out there that get the job done. I've recently implemented [Gallery](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Gallery) and really like it.